# What is the simplest way to solve this equation for b?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Whats the simplest way to solve this? $12b-\frac{b^2}{2} = 36$

I am trying to find $b$ where the the line $x=b$ divides a region into two equal parts of equal area.  The integral is $\int_{0}^{12}(12-x)~dx = 72$ so $\int_{0}^{b}(12-x)~dx=36$.  I believe I set this up correctly, if not how do I solve for $b$?

Thanks

Comment: That is a quadratic equation you have.

Comment: The simplest way is to ask someone else to answer it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Oppa for your extremely insightful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiplying by $2$ and rearranging we get
$$0=b^2-24b+72$$
using the quadratic formula we get
$$b_{1,2}=12\pm\sqrt{144-72}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: $b=12-\sqrt{144-72}$ thanks

Comment: and the other solution?

Comment: Well the other solution is $b=12+\sqrt{144-72}$, but that wouldn't work right? Since I am looking for a number between $0$ and $12$.

Comment: ok then is all to the best

Comment: yes i have it known yet

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: I have one more question.  How did you get $12\pm\sqrt{144-72}$ from $\frac{24\pm\sqrt{288}}{2}$?